# CSS Changes, Updates in ASP.NET Theme Does Not Show Up

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

I thought it may be cached, but for some reason that I don't know the changes I make in CSS file that is located in application theme does not show up. If I take that change and put in a CSS file outside of theme folder, let's root or a new folder, it does show up. This is a ASP.NET 4.0 application. Not sure where to look for the solution. Please advise.

Comment: Have you verified that you are applying the theme you think you're applying?  What theme did you tell the page to use?

Comment: Yes I have verified it. The thing is that asp pages have the themes. It does show up, it is just the new updates to the CSS do not show up & no it is not the cache. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't just put the Theme folder, create a sub folder and put under it. It is better to name both sub-folder and css file same.

Comment: There is a sub folder in there. I don't think that is the issue anyway. This used to work. It stopped all of a sudden.